# Ajuda com recuperar nós do Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-database

Quero recuperar todos os seguidores dos usuarios no firebase.

Tenho a seguinte estrutura no Firebase:

```
-seguidores
    -id amigo
        -id usuario
```

Para essa estrutura fiz o seguinte para recupera-la:

```
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        //Recupera dados de usuário logado
        usuarioLogado = dataSnapshot.getValue( Usuario.class );
        /*
         * Recuperar seguidores */
        DatabaseReference seguidoresRef = firebaseRef
                .child("seguidores")
                .child( idUsuarioLogado );
        seguidoresRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                seguidoresSnapshot = dataSnapshot;
                dialog.cancel();
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
    }
```

E fiz um For da seguinte forma:

```
for( DataSnapshot seguidores: seguidoresSnapshot.getChildren() ){}
```

Desse modo eu recupero todos através do Id do usuário.

Agora se minha estrutura fosse assim:

```
-usuarios
    -id usuario
```

Usando esse trecho de código:

```
DatabaseReference usuariosRef = firebaseRef
        .child("usuarios");
usuariosRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        usuariosSnapshot = dataSnapshot;

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Como eu faria um for para recuperar os ids desse tipo de estrutura?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se eu entendi corretamente a sua estrutura, vejamos um exemplo:

```
- usuarios
    - idDouSUAriOAWcjvS_jG
        - id: "idDouSUAriOAWcjvS_jG"
        - nome: "Francisco João"
        - idade: 18
```

A classe usuário pode parecer com esta:

```
public class Usuario {
    private String id;
    private String nome;
    private int idade;

    public Usuario() {}

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public int getIdade() {
        return idade;
    }

    public void setIdade(int idade) {
        this.idade = idade;
    }

}
```

Para recuperar apenas (mas todos) os ids:

```
DatabaseReference idsRef = firebaseRef.child("usuarios");
idsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        List<String> ids = new ArrayList();

        for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            Usuario u = child.getValue(Usuario.class);
            ids.add(u.getId());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) { }
});
```

Para recuperar todos os usuários:

```
DatabaseReference usuariosRef = firebaseRef.child("usuarios");
usuariosRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        List<Usuario> usuarios = new ArrayList();

        for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            Usuario u = child.getValue(Usuario.class);
            if (u != null) {
                usuarios.add(u);
            } 
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) { }
});
```

Para recuperar um usuário pelo Id:

```
DatabaseReference usuarioRef = firebaseRef.child("usuarios").orderByChild("id").equalTo("idDouSUAriOAWcjvS_jG");
usuarioRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {     
        for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            Usuario franciscoJoao = child.getValue(Usuario.class);
            // Supostamente cada usuário com seu id
            // Se for usar algo como orderbyChild("idade").equalTo(18), não pare o loop
            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) { }
});
```